# Translate curl post to python requests post

Tags: post, python-requests

I am trying to upload an XML file to an **IIS** server using **Python 3.8.1** and **requests**. I have successfully done this many times using **curl**. This works:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary @MS1481_20200204_163918_4461289.xml https://oursever.com/postHere
```

The XML file that I am attempting to upload is created earlier in the program. The filename is dynamically created using a series of strings concatenated together, including the current date and time in the middle.

This is how I am attempting to upload using Python:

```
postURL = 'https://oursever.com/postHere'
postXML = {'file': open(xmlfilename, 'rb')}
postResult = requests.post(postURL, files=postXML)
print(postResult)
```

I continue to get `<Response [400]>`. I can successfully upload immediately afterwards using curl. Suggestions?

Comment: [Here](https://curl.trillworks.com/)

Comment: I missed this earlier. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A 400 error indicates that something is wrong with your client side input.

Is the file getting properly opened and read? You should use either the `with` condition to open it,

```
with open(path) as f:
    print(type(f))
```

or make sure you read it with this `open(xmlfilename, 'rb').read()`

Try:

```
postURL = 'https://oursever.com/postHere'
postXML = {'file': open(xmlfilename, 'rb').read()}
postResult = requests.post(postURL, files=postXML)
print(postResult)
```

Comment: The ```.read()``` append did not work, still getting the 400 response. I had tried the ```with open(xmlfilename)``` approach earlier yesterday. I'll try it again. Perhaps I wrote it incorrectly.